# How to make the GameObjects interact with each other under the camera in Augmented Reality?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am new to Unity3D and currently developing a project, which is a mobile application with augmented reality features.

I have installed Unity3D and Vuforia extension for the AR features. My project consists of flashcards that are scanned through the camera and the 3D Object pops up according to the respective trackers. Here are some images for the flashcards.

[Flashcard 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtGiu.png)

[Flashcard 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iiobc.png)

As of now, I managed to make the 3D objects appear in each flashcard, but they are static.

I am trying to make them interact with each other, so that when the two flashcards are detected by the camera, the objects in each flashcard disappear and a single object appears.

I am also aware that I need to use OnCollision for this, but since I have no background or experience in Unity3D, I am unsure which type to use.

Please help me with the scripting so that I can carry on with my project.

Thanks in advance.